Light from an eclipse
Why do people fry their eyes staring at the sun during a solar eclipse?  Is it that they stare at the sun for a long time---longer than if they stared without an eclipse?  Or is it that during the eclipse the sun's light rays somehow become more dangerous?
I know that the Moon's gravitational pull will affect light (it's basically the principle that allows gravitational lensing), but I doubt the effect even amounts to one angstrom, hardly enough to change their nature.

You could do with leaving out all the unnecessary commentary and background and just ask the question directly as to whether gravitational lensing affects the wavelength of the light from the sun to earth.

I edited out superfluous information and foul language. However, it seems like you still have yet to pose a question. A question is a sentence that ends in a question mark, and I don't see one. Are you meaning to ask who is correct, you or your sister?

I didn't ask about gravitational lensing, There is no lensing ( probably from the Moon ). I asked whether the moon makes any meaningful  change to the light from the sun.

"I asked whether the moon makes any meaningful change to the light from the sun."  You also wrapped your question in a lot of blather.

I've edited out the blather.

@hft, Thank you for the editing, it makes the question much clearer  I didn't think that the language was foul by today's standards, and wanted to add self deprecating humor.

@WillO Thank you for the editing.

I have an answer on this topic here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/36629/16685

People generally avoid staring at the sun; it's bright and painful and will damage your eyes. During an eclipse people want to watch the eclipse happening and without approved darkened glasses they will damage their eyes. The light is just as bright and just as damaging to your retina. The only time you can view the eclipse safely without safety glasses is when it is total, then you are not viewing the sun itself only its corona.
see this link
The first rule of enjoying the eclipse is to avoid looking directly at the sun without eye protection. Even brief glances can cause permanent damage.
The only exception to this rule is for lucky spectators in the path of totality during the few minutes of the total eclipse, when the sun is fully blocked by the moon.
That link will also tell you three ways to safely view the eclipse (indirectly) without glasses.
As for gravitational lensing, you are right that the moon's effect is immeasurable. When Eddington confirmed in 1919 Einstein's GR the effect of the sun was to deflect light by only 1.75 arcseconds link

Thank you for your answer. I talked around the question and clarified it, because of this you talked around the answer. Also hft. Cleaned up the question.

The gravitational deflection of light by the Moon is around 25.9 microarcseconds.

@PM2Ring I'm impressed you did the calculation, but I think the red shaft would be more relevant.

@Thad Calculating gravitational light deflection is one of my hobbies. ;) Eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/805213/123208 Light gets blue shifted as it falls into a gravity well, but it gets red shifted as it climbs back out of the well. So the effect of the Moon on the wavelength of sunlight is pretty much neutral by the time the light reaches Earth. The light does get slightly blue shifted by the Earth, but it's mostly red shifted due to climbing out of the Sun's gravity well.

These shifts are small, but they directly relate to time dilation, so they're important if you want to synchronise atomic clocks across the Solar System to sub-nanosecond precision. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/809010/123208 & https://space.stackexchange.com/q/65783/38535

During the darkest parts of the eclipse, your pupils may dilate to adjust to the darkness. A reasonable hand-waving estimate for the difference in area between a fully-constricted pupil versus a fully-dilated pupil is a factor of 100.  This means that looking directly at a 95% eclipsed Sun might put one twentieth of the Sun's light onto your face — but if your pupil is exposing fifty times more area than usual, you might actually get more sunlight on your retina than staring directly at the full sun.  The eclipsed Sun might also fail to trigger your startle/squint/lookaway reflex.
