Does time go faster the higher you go?
The phrasing in the title is really bad, so let me clarify what I mean. Does time "go slower" at sea level than, for example, on the top of a mountain, according to the theory of relativity?
I'd like to know specifically the answer

according to SR only, without taking into account GR,
taking into account both SR and GR


In SR, no. In GR, yes, and it's been experimentally confirmed

to add to this: on a mountain, time would actually go slower, because there is more matter under you, i.e. more gravitational acceleration.

Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/809010/174766

This might help - Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?

It is answered here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/762899/why-does-time-flow-more-slowly-on-the-ground-than-on-a-mountain

@paulina No, time would not be slower on a mountain. You have a little bit more mass under you, but the fact that you moved further away from the large mass of Earth outweighs that.

In SR it would depend on the reference frame you are using. In an inertial reference frame where the clock on the mountain is moving faster then it will tick slower. But you will always be able to find an inertial reference frame where the opposite is true.
In GR the situation on the earth is well described by the weak field metric. Using that metric the clock at a lower gravitational potential (the one at sea level) will tick more slowly.

If I get farther from the center of the Earth, I move faster, because of Earth rotation. So, does time on a mountain go slower because of this, according to SR?

As I said in the answer, this depends on the reference frame. In a reference frame where the clock on the mountain is moving faster then it will tick slower. The inertial frame where the center of the earth is at rest is such a frame.

What about an inertial frame which is external to the Earth, for example the Sun?

See my answer: In a reference frame where the clock on the mountain is moving faster then it will tick slower. That is a general rule you can apply. You don’t need me to enumerate every possible frame.

But if I am at sea level I don't see any difference in time, since the top of the mountain is at rest from my viewpoint, right? So how is this possible?

@Elvis that frame is not an inertial frame. I have clarified my answer to specify inertial frames.

@Dale Not this way: in a higher gravitational potential the time slows down?

@HolgerFiedler the clock at the lower gravitational potential runs slower than the one at a higher potential. See, for example, the Pound Rebka experiment
